# Tab Order in Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I've referred to this [**MSDN ARTICLE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw(v=vs.100).aspx)

I'm using Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express - is there a quick way of seeing the tab order using this application?

There doesn't seem to be a `Tab Order` option in the `View` menu. Is this a feature left out of the express edition or am I looking in the wrong place?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Right click on the menu bar and choose customize, which is present at
  the last menu item.
- Click the commands tab and click rearrange button on it.
- You'll see a phrase saying: Choose a menu or toolbar to arrange below
  that you can see a radio button with tool bar as its text. select it.
- Click Add command, from categories choose view, from commands choose
  tab order then click OK.   Well, they're arranged alphabetically.
- Now click close and check the tab order button in the view toolbar
  and you'll find it.

  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have you view selected in your main window and not in your solution browser. This should give you the tab order option.

If still not present it could be it's not included in the Express edition.

Comment: thanks Jeroen - have I got my "view selected in your main window" in the screen print in the OP ?

Comment: i think so, can't see it like this